# jQuery tab postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery, user-interface

I am using jQuery remote tab with asp.net to load my .aspx pages.The problem is if suppose i have a main page called "Parent.aspx" which contains the jQuery tab and child page "Page1.aspx" which is loaded via remote tab into the "Parent.aspx".When i click on a server side button on my Page1.aspx, the whole window redirects to the Page1.aspx.I want it to remain on the Paernt.aspx itself.

My Code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#divEmployee').tabs(1, { remote: true });
});
```

should I add some thing to this, to achieve the above mentioned functionality

Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the how to section of the [jQuery Tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) documentation.

Open links in the current tab instead of leaving the page

```
$('#example').tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
        $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
            $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```